# How to use pip install Sybase python package

Tags: python, sybase

Run the Python in eclipse of windows environment

**import Sybase**
error: ImportError: No module named Sybase

Try to install use pip in command: **pip install Sybase**
error: Could not find a version that satisfied the requirement Sybase 
No matching distribution found for Sybase

How to create the Sybase connection in Python?

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Try looking at FreeTDS and `pymssql`; Sybase uses a compatible protocol.

Comment: Yes, I had tried, but there is another error in running:
My connection config: pymssql.connect(server='sybaseserver', port='4000', user='dev', password='password',database='db_name')      

running error : OperationalError: (20017, 'DB-Lib error message 20017, severity 9:\nUnexpected EOF from the server (sybaseserver:4000)\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (sybaseserver:4000)\n')

Comment: Did you try so select a [specific protocol version](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm)?

Comment: Also, I had tried sqlanydb, but still have error in running in same connection config

Error:    raise InterfaceError("Could not load dbcapi.  Tried: " + ','.join(names))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found

Comment: How to put the protocol version into connection parameters?

Comment: [`pymssql.connect`](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/ref/pymssql.html#pymssql.connect) has a parameter for tds version. (I had no idea. [How did I learn](https://www.google.com/search?q=pymssql+set+protocol+version&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)?)

Comment: I had tried setup an tds version into connection, but still the same error

pymssql.connect(server='sybaseserver', port='4000', user='dev', password='password',database='db_name', tds_version='7.1')

Comment: Can you even `telnet.exe` to host `sybaseserver`, port `4000`? If the server just closes connection on you, without waiting, or the connection is never established,, the problem may be elsewhere (e.g. allowed IP addresses or something).

Comment: tried, telnet successful, i think should be other problem